# Carrying Form Input Variables Over Multiple Pages

Tags: php, forms, session-variables

I have a form submission with a couple dropdowns and a text input field. I have the values being uploaded to a database which works fine, however I'm attempting to carry the $_POST values over to a third success page after processing them. I can't seem to get it to work regardless of research. There's obviously something that I'm doing wrong and just need a little help to pinpoint. File examples are below. Thank you in advance for any help.

**index.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["mynext"] = $_POST["mynext"];
$_SESSION["city"] = $_POST["city"];
$_SESSION["comment"] = $_POST["comment"];
?>
<form action="scripts/process.php" method="post">
            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="mynext">Choose your language</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="mynext" name="mynext" autocomplete="off" required>
                        <option class="engl" value="My Next" selected="selected">My Next</option>
                        <option class="span" value="Mi próximo">Mi próximo</option>
                        <option class="chin-simp" value="我的未來的">我的未來的</option>
                        <option class="chin-trad" value="我的未來的">我的未來的</option>
                        <option class="kore" value="나의 다음">나의 다음</option>
                        <option class="arme" value="ԻՄ ՀԱՋՈՐԴ">ԻՄ ՀԱՋՈՐԴ</option>
                        <option class="russ" value="МОЙ БУДУЩЕГО">МОЙ БУДУЩЕГО</option>
                        <option class="viet" value="TRONG TƯƠNG LAI CỦA TÔI">TRONG TƯƠNG LAI CỦA TÔI</option>
                        <option class="japa" value="私の次の">私の次の</option>
                        <option class="thai" value="ในอนาคตของฉัน">ในอนาคตของฉัน</option>
                        <option class="khmr-camb" value="របស់ខ្ញុំបន្ទាប់">របស់ខ្ញុំបន្ទាប់</option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-5 col-lg-3">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">Select where you live, work, or play</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="city" name="city" autocomplete="off">
                        <option value="LA" selected="selected">LA*</option>
                        <option value="Agoura Hills">Agoura Hills</option>
                    </select>
                </div> 
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 dynamic-is">
                <p class="engl">is</p>
                <p class="hidden span">es</p>
                <p class="hidden chin-simp">是</p>
                <p class="hidden chin-trad">是</p>
                <p class="hidden kore">는 입니다</p>
                <p class="hidden arme">-ն է՝</p>
                <p class="hidden russ">— это</p>
                <p class="hidden viet">là</p>
                <p class="hidden japa">は</p>
                <p class="hidden thai">คือ</p>
                <p class="hidden khmr-camb">-ն է՝</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-3 comment-wrapper">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="comment">Tell us what you’d like to see</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="comment" name="comment" placeholder="Type here" autocomplete="off" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-1">
                <button type="submit" name="mynext-submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Once submitted the form values get uploaded via the process.php shown below

**process.php**

```
<?php 
$mynext = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mynext');
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city');
$comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment');

if(!empty($comments)){

        $host = 'localhost';
        $user = '';
        $password = '';
        $dbname = '';

        $conn = new mysqli ($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

        if(mysqli_connect_error()){
                die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_error() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
        }else{
            $sql = "INSERT INTO nextla (mynext, city, comment) VALUES ('$mynext', '$city', '$comments')";

            if ($conn->query($sql)){
                    echo "<br>Input data is successful";
            }
            else{
                    echo "Error: ". $sql ."<br>". $conn->error;
            }
            $conn->close();
        }

}else{

    echo 'Please add a comment';
    die();

}

header( 'Location: ../comment-success.php' );

?>
```

Once processed I then want to display the form field information on the comment-success.php page below.

**comment-success.php**

```
<?php include("includes/header.php"); ?>

        <div class="banner sub-banner sub-careers">
            <img src="<?php echo $siteroot; ?>img/banner/sub-contact.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div> 
            <h1><?php echo $page; ?></h1>       
        </div>

        <div class="email-sent-container container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <h1 class="section-divider">Your Comments have been Submitted Successfully</h1>
                    <?php
                        echo $_SESSION["mynext"];
                        echo $_SESSION["city"];
                        echo $_SESSION["comment"];
                        session_unset();
                    ?>
                    <p>Thank you for your input. Click <a href="index.php">here</a> to return to the home page.</p>
                </div>
            </div>  
        </div>

<?php include ('includes/footer.php'); ?>
```

Can someone please help me find the solution. I'm sure it's something simple and I just seem to be overlooking it as I've been staring at this code for so long. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can store them in one or more cookies, you can use hidden fields in the forms to carry them over, or you can use sessions to save the values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am in fact attempting to use the $_SESSION function to achieve this, but what I have currently doesn't seem to be working. Are you able to see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this piece of code:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["mynext"] = $_POST["mynext"];
$_SESSION["city"] = $_POST["city"];
$_SESSION["comment"] = $_POST["comment"];
```

On the top pf the file that actually receives the POST

**process.php**

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION["mynext"] = $_POST["mynext"];
$_SESSION["city"] = $_POST["city"];
$_SESSION["comment"] = $_POST["comment"];

$mynext = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'mynext');
$city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city');
$comments = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'comment');
...
```

And add a `session_start();` to the top of every file that use sessions.

PS: You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: So would I then be able to call in the values into comment-success.php as shown above?

Comment: Yes. Try and see for yourself :)

Comment: I've changed the comment-success.php to this `echo $_SESSION["mynext"]; echo $_SESSION["city"]; echo $_SESSION["comment"]; echo "Simply a TEST";`, but all I get is the "Simply a TEST" shown. I'm sorry if this seems like hand holding, it's a learning process on my end.

Comment: add a `session_start();` to the top of comment-success.php

Comment: Ah, that worked, always something simple but yet overlooked. I appreciate all your help. So just to clarify anywhere I'm going to be using $_SESSION variables I need to add the session_start()?

Comment: Yes. You can include/require a file with `session_start();` instead, that will do the same. In the future, any other command needed to every file could be added to this file.